# How to Use count and Group By with Self join in the same table in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have a single table with columns of `st_name` and `id`. I need to get the count of `st_name` and Group by `st_name`. How do I do this?

Comment: Please add example data and desired results.

Comment: Station_name | ID                                                            val1            1                                                     val2            2                                                       Above is the Table format am having.need to get count of Station_name Group By ID.                                           my Query am trying so for is :                                      select station_name,count(*) as grp_cnt,
(select count(distinct station_name) from tbl_Training_Detail) as st_cnt
from tbl_Training_Detail group by MasterId

Comment: @Suren: That's very hard to read.  Please edit your answer to add your `CREATE TABLE` script and your best attempt so far.  Note that if you indent your code it'll be formatted as such (e.g., with a fixed-width font).

Answer (score 0):

```
select st_name, 
       count(*) as grp_cnt,
       (select count(distinct st_name) from your_table) as st_cnt
from your_table
group by st_name
```

Comment: `count(*) OVER() AS st_cnt` will also do the same thing.

Comment: cheers Juergen,but i need to group by with ID not st_name.while run with group by ID i got this error:  Column 'tbl_Training_Detail.Station_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SurendarCBE: Then please update your question to make clear what you are trying to do and please also add example data.

Comment: Station_name | ID                                                            val1            1                                                     val2            2                                                       Above is the Table format am having.need to get count of Station_name Group By ID.                                           my Query am trying so for is :                                      select station_name,count(*) as grp_cnt,
(select count(distinct station_name) from tbl_Training_Detail) as st_cnt
from tbl_Training_Detail group by MasterId

Comment: @Suren: As I said please add that to your question in a well formatted manner.