# how to Use Count and group by within the same table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Station_Name | ID
------------------
santo        |  1
berlin       |  2
fero         |  3
------------------
```

table name Training_detail

need to get the **Count of Station_Name Group by id.**
have tried the query to achieve this.
but got error how to achieve this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use count and Group By with Self join in the same table in sql server 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633094/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-with-self-join-in-the-same-table-in-sql-server-200)

Comment: _What_ have you tried? What is wrong with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Training_detail GROUP BY Station_Name`?

Comment: select A.station_name as Personnel,B.Station_Name from tbl_Training_Detail A
join tbl_Training_Detail B on A.MasterId=B.MasterId 
Group by A.MasterId

Comment: should group by id not with station_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code:

```
WITH S AS (SELECT COUNT(Station_Name)  as count,ID
FROM Training_detail
GROUP BY ID)
SELECT S.*,T.Station_Name
from s , Training_detail t
where T.ID=S.ID
```

Comment: with this i have done 80%.with this query i need to select the Station_name too.

Comment: while adding Station_name with this Query i got this error:                Column 'tbl_Training_Detail.Station_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'S'.

Comment: Im really sorry for my hurry dude. I edited it .learn my mistakes.

Comment: Cheers dude its working great.final one is to get only the distinct values from T.

Comment: ya sure will tickkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) Count, Station_Name from Training_detail group by Station_Name
```

Comment: want to group by with ID not with station_name

Comment: SELECT count(*) Count, Station_Name from Training_detail group by ID